# How can I align properly the words into a txt files?

Tags: python, file, alignment, txt

Good evening Everyone, I am David tzu a 9 years old, and I really need help with this problem about the alignment of the word properly, I tried the print only but it doesn't fit that much.

sample.txt consist of:

```
David Tzu           January 13, 2012        FriedChicken
Mama                March 15, 1980          Sphagetti
Papa                June 27, 1981           Burger
```

here's my code:

```
file = open("sample.txt", "r")
line_count = 1
for line in file:
    if line != "\n":
        line_count += 1
file.close()


with open("sample.txt") as fi:
    print("")
    for x in range(1,line_count):
        print(x, fi.readline().replace("\n", ""))
    print("")
```

the current result of the code above is like this:

```
 1   David Tzu           January 13, 2012        FriedChicken
 2   Mama                March 15, 1980          Sphagetti
 3   Papa                June 27, 1981           Burger
```

Expected Result:

```
      Name                  Birthday               Favorite Food
 1   David Tzu           January 13, 2012          FriedChicken
 2   Mama                March 15, 1980            Sphagetti
 3   Papa                June 27, 1981             Burger
```

I am really sorry for my terrible english, Hope you all understand what I am trying to convey.

additional code:
#Len of words

```
file = open("sample.txt", "r")
line_count = 1
for line in file:
    if line != "\n":
        line_count += 1
file.close()


with open("sample.txt") as fi:
    print("")
    for x in range(1,line_count):
        print(x, fi.readline().replace("\n", ""))
    print("")

file = open("Sample.txt", "rt")
data = file.readline()
words = data.split()

print(len(words))
```

Comment: see string formatting https://pyformat.info/

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have to only add line `Name                  Birthday               Favorite Food`

Comment: I don't understand why you open file two times - you should use `for number, line in enumerate(fi, 1):` and you don't have to count lines. OR you should do all at once in first `for`-loop.

Comment: if you don't know length of columns then first you would have to split every line into columns, and use `len()` for every column, and get `max(all_lengths_in_column)` - and later use this value to format columns with `string formatting`. But problem is to split line into columns - it may need regex which can use `\s{2,}` to split on `2 or more spaces`

Comment: Hi David - before we go further, I just want to clarify what you are after. From the expected output and the actual result you have posted above, it looks like all you are missing is the headers for the columns? Is including the headers what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your problem.

with your example it seems you need only to add first row with correct number of spaces

```
print('    Name                Birthday                Favorite Food')
```

Minimal working example.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory so everyone can simply copy it and test it.

```
text = '''David Tzu           January 13, 2012        FriedChicken
Mama                March 15, 1980          Sphagetti
Papa                June 27, 1981           Burger'''

import io

#fh = open("sample.txt")
fh = io.StringIO(text)

print('    Name                Birthday                Favorite Food')

line_count = 0

for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        line_count += 1
        print(f"{line_count:3} {line}")
```

Result:

```
    Name                Birthday                Favorite Food
  1 David Tzu           January 13, 2012        FriedChicken
  2 Mama                March 15, 1980          Sphagetti
  3 Papa                June 27, 1981           Burger
```

If you have more rows than 999 then you may need bigger number in  `{line_count:3}` and more spaces before `Name`

You have to only use `fh = open()`, `fh.write(line + '\n')`, `fh.close()` instead of `print()` to have it in file. OR you can open use `print(..., file=fh)` instead of `write()`

---

If you don't know how long are columns then you may need to read all lines, split to columns and then get `len()` for every value in columns and get `max(all_lenght_in_column)` for every column - and later you can use this value with `string formatting` like `{variable:lenght}`. But it may need `regex` to split columns on `2 or more spaces` (`\s{2,}`). So all this is much more complicated.

---

Eventually you may try to use `pandas` and `read_csv` with separator `\s{2,}`

```
text = '''David Tzu           January 13, 2012        FriedChicken
Mama                March 15, 1980          Sphagetti
Papa                June 27, 1981           Burger'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#fh = "sample.txt"
fh = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(fh, names=['Name', 'Birthday', 'Favorite Food'], sep='\s{2,}', index_col=False)

df.index += 1

print(df)
```

Result:

```
        Name          Birthday Favorite Food
1  David Tzu  January 13, 2012  FriedChicken
2       Mama    March 15, 1980     Sphagetti
3       Papa     June 27, 1981        Burger
```

And you can get it as `df.to_string()` and save in normal text file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if you know the space between the columns in file is a tab space.

```
with open("sample.txt") as ftr:        
    line_number = 1    
    print("\tName \tBirthday \tFavorite food")
    for line in ftr.readlines():
        print("%s \t%s" % (line_number, line))
        line_number += 1
```